# My JPEG files are not being rendered

Tags: html, image, path, src

I have a hosting account on GoDaddy and I'm using cPanel on a Lenix server. My HTML file is in the same folder as the 2 images.

However, when I run the HTML the rendered image frames are blank. Can someone help?

```
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">

<tr>

<td align="center" valign="center">
<img src="file://AnnBR2.jpg" style="width:800px;height:600px;" />
<br />
Bedroom
</td>

<td align="center" valign="center">
<img src="file://AnnBR1.jpg" style="width:800px;height:600px;"/>
<br />
Another shot of the bedroom.
</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is hosted on GoDaddy, you're probably accessing the page via `http://` or `https://`, not `file://`. You need to take out the `file://` part of the URLs.

[`file://`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) is used on the local network. For example, if your computer's hostname is `my-pc`, then `file://my-pc/Users` might display the `Users` directory of your computer. Note that web pages that are accessed over HTTP or HTTPS are usually blocked from accessing resources through `file://`.

When you're on the Internet, you'll be using HTTP or HTTPS for linking to just about all resources on a webpage. Those protocols are not just for accessing the page itself.

Files that are part of the same website as the page itself don't need to include the protocol, so `src="AnnBR2.jpg"` and `src="AnnBR1.jpg"` should be good enough.